# Creating DNN Portal through Code (or programming)?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have one portal with 3 modules inside it, now my requirement is i would like to create
new portal for every client registered in my DNN site.

So, i have one interface for registration, so as soon as client registers entirely new parent portal should be created with all the modules.

How can i achieve this functionality ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the site wizard to create template of the current portal and during client registration programmatically execute the template. You may also want to automate the site setup in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest digging into the admin files that come as part of the default DNN installation and look for the code that creates a new portal from there. It will ultimately be calling a stored procedure to create the necessary data in the SQL tables. You might get away with just calling the stored procs but the admin code probably calls several different ones to setup the default security settings.

Curiously what alias will each of these portals use? It's not clear why you need a complete portal for each user. The DNN segmentation already allows you to show different content based on role membership. Why the need for a whole portal per user?

Comment: its not actually portal per user but we are developing a product which can be used by multiple clients, so we would like to build a portal per client basis.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can easily do it! Login to host and go to portals. Click on create new protal.
See which control is responsible for creating new portal. you can simaply get it by using firebug and look into client id of link or text box.

Once you do that, you will find the code you can use.

tell me if you need more help with it, I'm good with what you want to do!